# How to dynamically add values to APIGEE Kvms when the number of entries depends on response array length

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, kvm, apigee

I'm getting array of objects as a response in apigee. i want to push these each objects to KVMs where in each object represents 1 KVM entry.

Suppose response is

```
Response = [{Key1: Value1},{Key2: Value2},{Key3: Value3}]
```

Seems I want to loop the KVM policy depending on the response length.

If not possible as I'm getting this from Lambda as a response, can DynamoDB be helpful? if yes then how?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, dynamodb can do that. You can create a dynamodb table with some schemes you like, for example :

Assume the values of Key1 are unique, set the Key1 as partition key and the others as attributes :

```
Key1 | attr1 | attr2
------------------------
Val1  | Val2  | Val3
```

Another schemes :

```
Key1 | attrs
------------------------
Val1  | {attr1: Val2, attr2: Val3}
```

```
PartitionKey | attrs
------------------------
UniqueVal     | {attr1: Val1, attr2: Val2, attr3: Val3}
```

In best practice, we use scheme with 2 keys, for example :

```
PartitionKey | SortKey | attrs
```

The last scheme allows you have combination of the keys as unique value i.e :

```
PartitionKey | SortaKey | attrs
abc                 | def           | jsonData1
abc                 | ghi           | jsonData2
dbe                 | ghi           | jsonData3
```

So you will have your preference on creating the table scheme with dynamodb and depends to your goal. You can manage indexing as well with dynamodb. But for your case, let you start in simple scheme above

You can find many links about dynamodb like the following one :

[Core components of dynamodb](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.CoreComponents.html)